# I am confused why is the return function printing a value on the console in my program. Isn't it just supposed to return a value?

Tags: python, pycharm

My program overloads the + operator to calculate the average GPA of 2 students.
In my definition of the **add** function, I expect the return statement to return the average value. I then want to print this 'returned value' using print().

However, the return statement also seems to print the average value along with the print statement.

The output was:

```
8.0 
8.0
```

I don't understand why the return statement prints the value. Isn't is just supposed to return the value?

From googling this issue online, I found the only time when return should print a value is when an interactive console is being used (I am using pycharm).

[prints twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7qj1.jpg)

[prints once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqdAM.jpg)

```
class student():

    def __init__(self, name, gpa):
        self.name = name
        self.gpa = gpa

    def __add__(x, y):
        return ((x.gpa + y.gpa)/2)

s1 = student("john", 9)
s2 = student("wick", 7)

avg = s1 + s2
print(s1 + s2)
```

Comment: It only prints `8.0`

Comment: It works just fine

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Anwarvic i can add a screenshot? it prints twice on my pc.

Comment: @Suyash, make sure there is no other print in your code, but I promise it prints only one output per print.

Comment: @Anwarvic sir, i copied the same code into another .py file. on running that it prints only once; on running this file it prints twice. I know i sound stupid saying that, but this happened. :(

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the output and added to your question please?

Comment: @Anwarvic just a second, i will

Comment: @Anwarvic i have added the screenshots sir

Comment: DON'T KNOW, THIS IS SORCERY :D

Comment: @Anwarvic then should i delete the question? as it might waste other peoples' time too.

Comment: Can you scroll down in the source code text editor where it prints twice to make sure there are no more lines of code?

Comment: @ChrisGraf there is a print there ;_;

Comment: @Suyash, no.. it's ok... maybe there is a good reason behind it

Comment: thank you to all those who responded and apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: @ChrisGraf should i delete this question now?

Comment: As you wish, you might as well post the problem as an answer so that others see what the mistake was. I can't tell you if this should be deleted or not. I can also post the problem as an answer if you wanna give me credit but I don't mind if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in the [first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7qj1.jpg) there is more source code when you scroll down. Check if a print exists there...